# is linearisation holomorphic?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, algebraic-groups

Suppose we have a smooth complex projective variety $X$ with a holomorphic action of a complex reductive algebraic group $G$ (i.e. the map $X \times G \rightarrow X$ is holomorphic). Suppose that the group action can be linearised i.e. the group action lifts to a holomorphic action on the space of some very ample line bundle (by bundle isomorphisms). Then we get an induced action of $G$ on the ambient projective space of some embedding of $X$ (since we have $G$-representation  $H^{0}(X,L)$ ). **Question:** Is this group action holomorphic?

Stated another way, the linearization gives a natural injective group homomorphism $Aut(X) \rightarrow Aut(\mathbb{P}^{n}) = PGL(n+1,\mathbb{C})$, is this map holomorphic? (Note that there is a canonical complex lie group structure on $Aut(X)$, so the question is well-posed). I have looked in several sources, for example the book of Kobayashi on transformation groups, but they never say this explicitly (I have a feeling it is so obvious that they don't bother to state this, but I want to check).

Comment: What do you mean by "lifts"? Do you mean lifts to a holomorphic action? (Think of $X=\{x\}$ as an extreme case: A group-theoretic lift need not even be continuous.)

Comment: Yes, I mean it lifts to a holomorphic action by bundle isomorphisms. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: No, this is not what I meant. You can have a discontinuous homomorphism ${\mathbb C}^*\to {\mathbb C}^*$ for example.

Comment: Please could you explain again what you meant?

Comment: As I already said, you have to define "lift". So, far, it is an undefined concept.

Comment: Let $Tot(L)$ denote the total space of the bundle, it has a canonical structure of a complex manifold. By lift, I meant a holomorphic group action i.e. a holomorphic map $G \times Tot(L) \rightarrow Tot(L)$ satisfying the usual axioms of a group action, such that for any $g \in G$  the fibre over $p \in X$ is mapped linearly by $g$ to the fibre over $g.p$.

Comment: OK, then the action on $H^0(X,L)$ is holomorphic. You can see this by restriction to $p^{-1}(U)\cong U\times {\mathbb C}$ where $U$ is a small open subset of $X$ and $p: L\to X$ is the bundle map.

Comment: ok I see, Thanks!